# Resin printing on Voxelab Polaris

Tags: resin

I've recently got an Elegoo Mars-like resin printer which is called Voxelab Polaris. So far, I have a lot of success with it, but one piece is proving really tough to print and I'm hoping for advice!

[These Settlers Of Catan tiles](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2035221) are natively about 90x97 mm.

It's too big to print flat on my 130x82x155 mm print bed, so I've been trying to print it at a variety of angles including vertically. When printed vertical, it tends to warp along the long axis, and when done at an angle including supports there's not enough landing area to stick it to the print bed.

I've tried printing two together back-to-back, but in Chitubox I can't find a way to add supports between two pieces on the bed (only from each piece to the bed).

Anyone got any insights about how I might print this in resin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print flat, you could easily print all parts at 90 %: the bounding box dimensions now are 81.16 x 88 mm - and as a result, you can print some other parts flat next to it but not more than one tile at the same time. Remember to print all cities and roads at 90 % too.

Comment: Thanks - I'd thought about scaling it but wanted it to be compatible with the Catan pieces from our exiting copy of the game. I will look again at this, though. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: if the answer doesn't answer your problem, you don't need to accept it - scaling is just the option I would take to enforce flat printing.